# Trouble following the call stack in a Binary Search Tree Inorder Tree Traversal call

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, inorder

I was hoping someone could clarify how the call stack works in this recursive call for me please. I think I am starting to wrap my head around recursion and backtracking which has been an issue for me and I think I have dwindled the problem down to one specific area.

So, the confusion came up when I was practicing my BST Inorder Traversals in Python.

Here is the implementation of a BST Tree I used to represent the following array [10, 14, 19, 27, 31, 35, 42].

I provide 3 Inorder Traversal solutions because I was trying to understand how the recursive call stack worked. For options 1 and 2 when I keep the result outside of the recursive call I get how the solution works. But for Option 3 when we do res = and res = res + I am confused how the call stack keeps track of this to return an answer. I think once I get how the res is saved in the call stack I will be able to understand how recursion works. Could someone walk me through how this works please.

FYI: I don't run the solution with all three functions named the same it was for the sake of the example.

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = data

    def insert(self, data):
        node = Node(data)
        if self.data:
            if data < self.data:
                if self.left is None:
                    self.left = node
                else:
                    self.left.insert(data)
            elif data > self.data:
                if self.right is None:
                    self.right = node
                else:
                    self.right.insert(data)
        else:
            self.data = data

    def printTree(self):
        if self.left:
            self.left.printTree()
        print(self.data)
        if self.right:
            self.right.printTree()

# Option 1) I can follow the call stack if I implement it like this keeping the result out of the helper function
    def inorderTraversalRecursive(self, root):
        res = []

        def inorder(root):
            if not root:
                return
            inorder(root.left)
            res.append(root.data)
            inorder(root.right)

        inorder(root)
        return res

# Option 2) I can also follow the stack when I implement it like this and print the root with end=''
    def inorderTraversalRecursive(self, root):
        if root is None:
            return
        self.inorderTraversalRecursive(root.left)
        print(root.data, end=' ')
        self.inorderTraversalRecursive(root.right)

# Option 3) I have an issue understanding once I put the result into the if root statement
    def inorderTraversalRecursive(self, root):
        res = []
        if root:
            res = self.inorderTraversalRecursive(root.left)
            res.append(root.data)
            res = res + self.inorderTraversalRecursive(root.right)
        return res


#Creating the Tree
root = Node(27)
root.insert(14)
root.insert(35)
root.insert(10)
root.insert(19)
root.insert(31)
root.insert(42)
print(root.inorderTraversalRecursive(root))
```

Comment: The call stack doesn't need to keep track of it.  Remember that `res` is local to the function.  EVERY call has its own copy.  The `res = res +` line is just tacking on the list returned by the recursive call.  That makes MY `res` larger, and I can return it to my caller.  Each invocation only has to worry about its list.

Comment: I see, I see, I see. It makes sense now. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @TimRoberts sorry, I forgot to tag you in the first thank you. If you wouldn't mind I also have another question and it is on a recursive call in the def insert(self,data) function. How does the self.left.insert(data) work? I was thinking about this and think I might have a bad implementation. Is it saying on the Left Node call the insert  function with the data and try again? Or, should I create an insert function that passes in another parameter to account for the node/root we are at to keep recursively calling the traverse.

Comment: The recursion is just traversing the nodes until it gets to one with an empty slot on one side or the other.  When it finds an empty slot, it fills it.

Comment: @TimRoberts Okay hmmm I am honestly still a little confused, I think it is something from a high level I can remember it works. I am in the debugger right now trying to figure it out. I changed it around to have it read a little cleaner with some optimizations (Sharing in a comment after this). I guess I am confused on the concept of making a recursive call on self.left an item we initialized I didn't think that would be possible. So the recursion call is just saying look go to the left node if it is there then recursively call insert again passing in data??

Comment: @TimRoberts I finally had the aha moment in the debugger. I greatly appreciate your time again. Thank YOU!

So since we initialized left we can keep calling left until there is no more than it returns with the fill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I rewrote the function in the hope that it will help to understand it better:

```
def inorderTraversalRecursive(self, root):
    if root:
        return self.inorderTraversalRecursive(root.left)\
              +[root.data]\
              +self.inorderTraversalRecursive(root.right)
    return []
```

P.S.1. In your code the name of the function (variant 3) is `inorderTraversal` - probably a spelling mistake.

P.S.2. I wonder why there is `if self.data:` block in the `insert` function. If `self.data` is set to `0` it won't be recorded?

P.S.3. I hope i did everything right. I dare say, Recursion is a slippery subject.

Comment: P.S.1 good catch I forgot I renamed the function. 
P.S.2 You have to do it to set the root node when initialized i have it set to self.data = data so it checks if there is something there before traversing else it set self.data = data or maybe I was wrong and I should've set self.data = node but it still worked that way. I have to look into that further